# How do I Use MD5 in JWT spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt, md5

I am using spring boot in my application and default security feature i.e. JWT is used.It is using Signature Algorithm "SignatureAlgorithm.HS512" for encryption.
I want to use mD5 to get more security. Can someone let me know hoe to integrate MD5 in spring security?

Comment: Actually, md5 is less secure then SHA512 (if you use properly), nowadays md5 considered cryptographically broken.
I suppose you use io.jsonwebtoken (not mentioned in the question).
SignatureAlgorithm.HS512 is well enough with proper salt.

Comment: Yes I am using io.jsonwebtoken

Comment: @zlaval Is there any way or example or a method to prove sha is way to better than MD5?

Comment: Yes that method is called ”googling”

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2994/what-is-the-recommended-replacement-for-md5


https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/what-are-the-differences-between-md5-sha-and-rsa


https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/199


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5


and of course the documentations, publications etc